# how to have combined header in perl for windows and linux

Tags: linux, perl

```
My development environment is windows and hosting environment is Linux. At the time of development i have the header:

"#!c:/perl64/bin/perl.exe"
```

while hosting on web server, i need to change header in all Perl files to:

```
"#!/usr/bin/perl"
```

This process is error prone, if i miss something. Is that possible combining two headers in Perl file and depend on the OS, it picks correct one?

Comment: As far as I know `#!` is a UNIX-only thing, e.g. windows only looks at the file extension and does not look at `#!` to know how to execute a file.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that's correct you don't need a shebang line on Windows.

Comment: @Matt If i remove `#!c:/perl64/bin/perl.exe` then not able to execute the script.

Comment: Hmmm what version of Perl are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: You shouldn't need a shebang on Windows with ActivePerl.

Looks like you're using ActiveState Perl (`C:\perl64` by default, Strawberry uses `C:\strawberry`). Despite them historically being a UNIX-y thing, ActiveState parses shebang lines in Perl files, but just to get the interpreter flags (like `-T` for taint checks), but you are not using any interpreter flags, so you should not need the shebang on Windows.

**If your script "doesn't execute" on Windows (specific error would be helpful here) without the shebang, then something else is wrong.** Make sure your script has a .pl extension, and make sure that your ActivePerl installation has been set as the default for .pl files. Here are the installation notes:

http://docs.activestate.com/activeperl/5.18/install.html

Also, according to the above docs:

> On Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista systems ActivePerl installations must be performed by a privileged user only. If you install ActivePerl without full administrator privileges, the following problems occur: ... PerlScript file associations are not created

On the Linux side, you also only need the shebang if running the script as an executable as in `./my-script.pl`, rather than manually specifying the interpreter as in `perl my-script.pl` (or, again, if you need interpreter flags). On Linux/UNIX-based systems, the canonical recommendation for a shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env perl`, to obviate the need for a hardcoded path to the interpreter.